# AppV 5.0 SP3-Unable to launch an application from icon in a Virtual Environment

Tags: process, virtual, environment, launch, appv

I have a situation here where I made a Virtual Environment to link 2 AppV 5.0 SP3 applications.

The AppV5 packages talk to each other in a funny way!! and I said that because once launched the main application I can see the connections created by the other AppV5 but if I launch the application icon alone from the 2nd application this one doesn't seems to find the main application process so it sends an error saying that the application does not exists.

TN3270 Plus is the main process the rest are just connections

![TN3270 Plus is the main process the rest are just connections][1]

Launching SCAE or SCAI connection gives this error

![Launching SCAE or SCAI connection gives this error][2]

So I'm troubleshooting this case and I came to a conclusion that doing a script to make the icons point to the other AppV 5 bubble main process it may work directly from the icons as it should. But what kind of script will be better and easy to integrate while sequencing the 2nd application?

I thought that a CMD will be a good candidate but so far Not a great success. Its launching CMD process inside the bubble and it remains static and visible to be able to type some commands to launch the application, this is great to let the technicians to troubleshoot issues but for users they are Not supposed to see the CMD window at all but just to be able to automatically launch the Main application process, maybe for a couple of seconds will be fine but not to keep it open all the time.

I came across from this site that shows how to execute an AppV5 bubble process but so far is not working the way it should be to the users. Notice that both applications are in AppV 5 and linked with a Virtual Environment and the case they show on the site below is a Locally installed application with an AppV 5 bubble:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/gladiatormsft/archive/2013/04/24/app-v-5-0-launching-native-local-processes-within-the-virtual-environment.aspx

Any ideas on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not much of an anwer, but I can't comment so there you go.

It sounds like you need to get some ProcMon on...
It would help if you could indicate where the icons are in the package(s) - are these 'for' published shortcuts or something else?

Another angle that may be worth considering: Are you launching the applications with the ConnectionGroup IDs or Package IDs?

We've typicaly avoided grouping because it's so much more complciated understanding what VFS elements are at play and how the layers of glass affect the application itself.

Is this just about a .ICO file?  Of course throwing these into other App-V's (or even outside the App-V) is perfectly fine, if a dirty work-around.

https://benjiappfactory.wordpress.com/

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.